# vuejs update value in template from a promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to VueJS and find the documentation lacking but I'm trying to work on a component where it sets a default value to comment count to 0 but then when a promise returns a value I want to update this in the view.

```
Vue.component('commentsCount', {
    template: `
      <strong class="t-bold">{{count}}</strong>
    `,
    data: () => ({ count: 0 }),
    created: () => {
      this.count = Review.stats(productCode)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.count);
          return res.count;
        });
      console.log(this);
    },
  });
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but this gives me the following errors and I've been on it for the past hour.

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'count' of undefined"
>
> found in
>
> --->

and this error which is on the line `this.count = Review.stats(productCode)`

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'count' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

You should set the value in the `.then` callback. Also don't use arrow functions to `created` (and other methods), or you will lost the context of `this`. Try this:

```
Vue.component('commentsCount', {
  template: `
    <strong class="t-bold">{{count}}</strong>
  `,
  data: () => ({ count: 0 }),
  created () {  // can't be an arrow function
    Review.stats(productCode)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.count);
        this.count = res.count;  // set count here
      });
    console.log(this);
  },
});
```

Comment: I get the following error on the `this.count = res.count` >Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'count' of undefined

Comment: Don't use arrow functions to `created()`

Comment: Actually scrap this I had to change the layout to `created() {` because of linting